# browserify multiple modules | with envify and brfs

Tags: javascript, browserify

```
browserify -t [ envify --NODE_ENV production , brfs ] index.js -o dist/javascripts/bundle.js
```

or

```
browserify -t [ envify --NODE_ENV production ] brfs index.js -o dist/javascripts/bundle.js
```

How to use multiple none of above works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `-t` multiple times. Try this:

`browserify -t [ envify --NODE_ENV production ] -t brfs -o dist/javascripts/bundle.js index.js`

The same is true for browserify plugins.